# what does this icon mean in SQL developer after running a query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running a large query and I don't end up with any output under the "query result" tab. what does this icon mean (circled in red)? 
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in the log panel, an error maybe?